# Парсинг значения из контролера

Tags: php, laravel

У меня такой вопрос. Как мне иммея контролер, спарсить с него значнеие в blade?
Вот как я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
{{ app/Http/Controller/UsersController::AmmountUsers()->vsego }}
```

При попытки открыть старницу с blade, где прописана функция. Пишет это:

```
Use of undefined constant app - assumed 'app'
```

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: может из контроллера в представление надо данные то передавать, а на наоборот?

Comment: @teran Т.е, черз compact?

Comment: @Snegan, просто любым способом передать в Вид, а не получать в самом Виде.. Хм, а разве `app` не надо с большой?

Comment: @teran return View::make('pages.users')->with('vsego', $vsego);

А в blade: {{ $vsego}}
Не работает

Comment: @teran Я пробовал со всех, и даже слеши обратные. Не работает

Comment: @Snegan, а почему не `view('pages.users', ['vsego' => $vsego]);`? И что пишет при Вашей попытке вывести?

Comment: @entithat Undefined variable: vsego